# CAN Bus Voltage Discrepancy

Tags: can

I’m currently using a sysWORXX USB-CANmodul1 to communicate with a Maxim MAX3051 CAN Transceiver on a custom PCB of mine. I've been having issues with the modul1 losing connectivity with the board. The CAN lines are short (~1m) and terminated at both ends with a 120 Ohm resistor between CAN_H and CAN_L.

It's my understanding the CAN Bus should have a recessive state voltage of ~2.5V and a dominant state voltage ~3.5V and ~1.5V for CAN_H and CAN_L respectively.

However when I measure the CAN signals from each device with a scope that's not what I'm getting. See below [image: CAN Bus on Scope]

I've poured over the datasheets of both of these devices to no avail. Links to those are below.
My main question is does anyone know what is going on here?

https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3051.pdf

https://www.systec-electronic.com/fileadmin/Redakteur/Unternehmen/Support/Downloadbereich/Handbuecher/L-487e_02_05_USB-CANmodul.pdf

Comment: Did you connect CAN_GND? Mandatory when using floating tranceivers.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that in the post but I do have a common ground running in between both devices.